# Video splash screen for Windows Form in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

i need help in adding a Video splash screen for Windows Form in C#.net . I tried to browse through different solutions and they were too difficult to implement . I found the simplest working code for adding an image as a splash screen which works amazingly well . If someone can help me the change the below code to use a video instead .

Code :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        bool done = false;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
        {
            using (var splashForm = new SplashForm())
            {
                splashForm.Show();
                while (!done)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                splashForm.Close();
            }
        });

        Thread.Sleep(3000); // Emulate hardwork
        done = true;
        Show();
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be a video? Is it an option to iterate through an image sequence?

Comment: @tweellt +1. If a video isn't required, you could also look into an animated GIF.

Comment: Based on what you've said, they will all be "too difficult to implement", I think.  You have to have something that can render the video, select and use appropriate codecs, etc.  You can't just plop a video on a form and expect magic.